# Timepicker android interval

Tags: java, android, intervals, android-timepicker

I have a TimePicker with an interval of 30 minutes. When I open up a custom dialog with this picker it works well and it shows me 2 choices correctly (0, 30) in the minutes spinner. But, when I confirm and I come back to the activity it shows me a wrong result like: 10:01 instead 10:30. That's the method I use to set the interval

```
 public static void setTimePickerInterval(TimePicker timePicker) {
        try {
            NumberPicker minutePicker = (NumberPicker) timePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("minute", "id", "android"));
            minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
            minutePicker.setMaxValue((60 / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) - 1);
            List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            }
            minutePicker.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues.toArray(new String[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
```

`TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL` is set as 30. And that's what i wrote in the activity inside the method that open a custom dialog with the picker

```
// Get time picker object.
        TimePicker timePicker = customView.findViewById(R.id.timePickerExample);
        Utils.setTimePickerInterval(timePicker);
        timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
        timePicker.setHour(hour);
        timePicker.setMinute(minute);
        dpStartDate.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                MainActivity.this.year = year;
                MainActivity.this.month = month;
                MainActivity.this.day = day;
            }
        });

        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onTimeChanged: " + minute +" "+ hour);
                MainActivity.this.hour = hour;
                MainActivity.this.minute = minute;
            }
        });
```

Log.i(TAG, "onTimeChanged: " + minute +" "+ hour); shows what I'm setting. The hours are corrected, minutes not. It seems that instead shows "0, 30" it shows and select "0, 1". Any idea?